# Is it possible to access the member of a user-defined struct in SystemVerilog using VPI and verilator?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, verilator

In SystemVerilog, we can use our own user-defined data structure, as the example below:

```
typedef struct packed {
    logic [riscv::VLEN-1:0]   pc;            
    logic [TRANS_ID_BITS-1:0] trans_id;     
    fu_t                      fu;            
    fu_op                     op;           
    logic [REG_ADDR_SIZE-1:0] rs1;           
    logic [REG_ADDR_SIZE-1:0] rs2;           
    logic [REG_ADDR_SIZE-1:0] rd;           
    riscv::xlen_t             result;        
    logic                     valid;         
    logic                     use_imm;      
    logic                     use_zimm;
    logic                     use_pc;       
    exception_t               ex;            
    branchpredict_sbe_t       bp;           
    logic                     is_compressed; 
} scoreboard_entry_t;
```

For now, we don't need to know what exactly these members represent. What we can see is a user-defined data strucuture in SystemVerilog. And later we instantiate this struct as an input port in a module:

```
input  scoreboard_entry_t        issue_instr_i/*verilator public_flat_rd*/,
```

As you see,  `issue_instr_i` is of this data struct and it is exposed to verilator. When I try to access it via VPI:

```
vpiHandle issue_instr =vpi_handle_by_name((PLI_BYTE8*)"TOP.core.issue_instr_i", NULL);
s_vpi_value v1;
v1.format = vpiHexStrVal;
vpi_get_value(issue_instr, &v1);
printf("instruction: %s\n", v1.value.str);
```

Apparently it only gives me a long string of hexadecimal values.
Could anyone let me know how to access a specific member in this struct? I tried setting the VPI handle as `issue_instr_i.rs1` etc, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packed struct, if you know bit sizes of its members, you can use 'vpiBinStrVal' to get a binary string. You can use returned bits to segment them, according to the size of your struct. For example for the following struct

```
   struct  packed {
      logic [3:0]a;
      logic [1:0]b;
   } v;
```

it might return `101011` where first 4 bits (1010) belong to `a` and the last two (11) belong to `b`. With unpacked structs it will not work though.

However, you should be able to access struct elements by names (if it is implemented in verilator). In vcs the following works ok:

```c
void testme() {
    vpiHandle stAll = vpi_handle_by_name("top.sram.v", 0);

    s_vpi_value v1;
    v1.format = vpiBinStrVal;
    vpi_get_value(stAll, &v1);
    vpi_printf("struct: %s\n", v1.value.str);
    
    vpiHandle va = vpi_handle_by_name("top.sram.v.a", 0);
    vpi_get_value(va, &v1);
    vpi_printf("struct.a: %s\n", v1.value.str);

    vpiHandle vb = vpi_handle_by_name("top.sram.v.b", 0);
    vpi_get_value(vb, &v1);
    vpi_printf("struct.b: %s\n", v1.value.str);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried it and Verilator threw out an error "vpi_get_value: Unsupported vpiHandle ((nil))" . So it seems that using this way to access the member of a struct is not feasible for Verilator.

Comment: I suggest to put a question in a verilator forum.

Comment: already did and got a response today. The developer says that Verilator "doesn't support structure member access" and " this won't be supported for a long time". So I am afraid taking a substring as you mentioned in the first place might be the only way to work.

Comment: hello, the developer said he didn't think verilator would support this feature very soon, so do you have any other idea that might solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each member of the struct, and possibly recursively if the embedded members are structs as well

```
void C_code() {
  vpiHandle s,itor,member;
  s=vpi_handle_by_name((PLI_BYTE8*)"top.s", NULL);
  vpi_printf("%s\n", vpi_get_str(vpiFullName, s) );
  if (vpiStructVar == vpi_get(vpiType,s)) {
    itor = vpi_iterate(vpiMember,s);
    while (member = vpi_scan(itor)) {
      vpi_printf("\t%s\n", vpi_get_str(vpiFullName, member) );
    }
  } else {
    vpi_printf("Not a struct");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. but I get the error messages that `"error: ‘vpiStructVar’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘vpiStringVal’?"` and `"error: ‘vpiMember’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘vpiMemory’?"` Are these two types implemented in VPI?

Comment: Did you `#include "sv_vpi_user.h"`

Comment: no, but `#include <vpi_user.h>`, and when I added `#include "sv_vpi_user.h"`, the error turns to be  `fatal error: sv_vpi_user.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like Verilator has very limited VPI support for Verilog and no support for SystemVerilog.

Comment: yes I believe so

Comment: hello, the developer said he didn't think verilator would support this feature very soon, so do you have any other idea that might solve this problem?